# How can I get started developing a site in Arabic in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, internationalization

I would like to develop a website using ASP.NET in an Arabic language.

What would be some good places to begin?

Useful advice to keep in mind?

Comment: this seems like a perfectly reasonable (if vague) question

Answer (score 2):

I did some of this in a former life, here's what I recall:

Is it going to be just ar-foo? If not (and I would always encourage thinking about the future possibilities), then having a page layout which is either flexible enough to handle RTL *and* LTR or switchable is going to be a big deal. That includes moving elements like the ubiquitous left-hand menu.

Make sure your character encoding supports arabic and is completely standardised from the DB up. XML/XSLT docs are notorious for being forgotten about here.

It's unlikely but possible that calendars will be a problem. You'll *probably* get away with using a western calendar in a business application, but the [hijri calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar) not only varies by country, but in an unpredictable pattern by astronomical event.

Finally, be very very careful with your graphics content. Again, this is unlikely to be a problem, but it's a big one if it does come up. I believe my company at the time actually ran stuff past a cleric at the local mosques community centre.