# Arabic web fonts

Tags: php, web-applications, web, arabic

I want to know how to use arabic fonts on website. I want to made web application in arabic language. So tell me any free library of arabic fonts. And also tell me does ASP.NET have built-in support for arabic language. If I want to built an application using PHP what should I do?

Comment: **Yes, definitely, you can create an Arabic-language application in ASP.Net.** [Here is one place](https://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/msdn/arabicsupp.aspx#1) you could start to learn how to do this. It begins at the beginning, telling you how to install Visual Studio for programming in Arabic. And here is information about [bi-directional support.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6eedwbtt.aspx) And here is an [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371446/how-can-i-get-started-developing-a-site-in-arabic-in-asp-net) very similar to yours whose answer might be helpful. And fi

Comment: ok. But what's the solution if I built this application on PHP. Is there any free library available to do this type of work?

Comment: While we wait for a PHP person to show up, try searching for "arabic php" here. You will find [Recommendations for translating an app in arabic tagged with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991188/recommendations-for-translating-an-app-in-arabic) and [How can I add arabic language with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015330/how-can-i-add-arabic-language-with-php) there, and more.

Comment: And there are more than 3,000 [questions here about arabic fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=arabic+font).

Comment: I am answering the question "And also tell me does ASP.NET have built-in support for arabic language. If I want to built an application using PHP what should I do?"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts)?

You can easily import fonts to your web application, for example, adding the following code to header:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidarabicnaskh.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

then you can use the font in your CSS like following:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Droid Arabic Naskh', 'Monda', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering the part of your question about free Arabic fonts. You can find some nice ones [here](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Arabic.html), but [here](http://software.sil.org/arabicfonts/) are two really beautiful ones.  I hope that helps a bit.